# Liferay portlet not recognized in portal

Tags: javascript, liferay, vaadin, portlet

I have deployed a chart-portlet in liferay portal. It's showing under the plugins section and I am able to add it on to the page. However when the page is reloaded it gives the error "Failed to load the bootstrap javascript: /chart-portlet/VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js".

The path it is trying to access is "https://www.exmapleportal.com/chart-portlet/VAADIN/vaadinBootStrap.js". However in application server (IBM websphere 7) the portlet is successfully deployed with context root as /chart-portlet and referred file is physically available on the server.

It seems deplolyed portlet is not recognized.

I am using Liferay 6.1 EE and application server is IBM Websphere 7.

Any help is much appreciated to resolve this matter.

Comment: Did you check the file referring this file via URL rather than the available file on server?

Answer (score 0):

I expect you need to add this into your web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>VaadinServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VaadinServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```